# Prove that $1\cdot 1! + 2\cdot 2! +\dots+n\cdot n! = (n + 1)! - 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

(whenever $n$ is a non-negative integer)

I did the basic step $P(1)$ and found the statment $P(n+1)$

I now have $(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)\cdot(n+1)!$

This should equal $(n+2)! - 1$, but how do I show that?

Comment: Put aside $-1$ and then factor the term $(n+1)!$ over the others.

Comment: you can use induction

Answer (score 2):

You have two terms containing the expression $(n+1)!$. Put these together and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)!$$
$$=(1+(n+1))(n+1)!-1$$
$$=(n+2)(n+1)!-1$$
$$=(n+2)!-1$$

Comment: See this for formatting tips
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

For $n=k$ , let $$\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\times j\,!=(k+1)!-1$$
If $n=k+1$ we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}j\times j\,!=(k+1)\times(k+1)!+\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\times j\,!=(k+1)\times(k+1)!+(k+1)!-1\\
\qquad=(k+1)!(k+1+1)-1=(k+1)!(k+2)-1=(k+2)!-1$$